# Raspberry PI - python code to read SMS not working when running under cron

Tags: python, bash, shell, cron, raspberry-pi

I made a python code to read SMS from SIM800 module, that is connected to a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and it is working like a charm when I run it on a terminal or another IDE.
Here is the expected result:

```console
safemonitor@safemonitor:~ $ python3 sms.py
--------------------------------------------
11-08-2021 11:37:27
Conexao OK
+5511xxxxxxxxx
gsm
Leitura SMS OK
SMS recebidos:  1
Telefone:  +5511xxxxxxxxx -> OK
Comando:  gsm  -> OK

Apagando todas as mensagens

Valida SMS OK
Modulo desconectado com sucesso
safemonitor@safemonitor:~ $
```

In other words, I send a SMS text to SIMCARD, my routine identifies the sender number and text sent and validate both information.

But when running under cron it identifies nothing, like this:

```console
safemonitor@safemonitor:~ $ python3 sms.py
--------------------------------------------
11-08-2021 11:41:18
Conexao OK
Leitura SMS OK
SMS recebidos:  0
Valida SMS OK
Modulo desconectado com sucesso
safemonitor@safemonitor:~ $
```

Here is cron table:

```console
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0-55/5 * * * * bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh 
1-59/3 * * * * bash /home/safemonitor/comandos.sh
4,34 * * * *  bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/console.sh
@reboot /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh
```

I have 3 scripts been called from cron and yes, first one is called every 5min, second every 3min, thrid every 4th and 34th minutes and also at boot I call the first one.

This is the script to run python code:

```console
safemonitor@safemonitor:~ $ cat comandos.sh 
#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/safemonitor/sms.py 2>&1 1>>/home/safemonitor/log/sms.log &
safemonitor@safemonitor:~ $
```

I also tried to run python directly from cron without success, like this:

```console
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0-55/5 * * * * bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh 
1-59/3 * * * * python3 /home/safemonitor/sms.py 2>&1 1>>/home/safemonitor/log/sms.log &
4,34 * * * *  bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/console.sh
@reboot /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh
```

I'm not using root user, my user is safemonitor with root rights

Here is part of the syslog:

```console
Aug 11 11:30:01 safemonitor CRON[5698]: (safemonitor) CMD (bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh ^M)
Aug 11 11:31:01 safemonitor CRON[5729]: (safemonitor) CMD (bash /home/safemonitor/comandos.sh^M)
Aug 11 11:34:02 safemonitor CRON[5783]: (safemonitor) CMD (bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/console.sh^M)
Aug 11 11:34:02 safemonitor CRON[5782]: (safemonitor) CMD (bash /home/safemonitor/comandos.sh^M)
Aug 11 11:35:01 safemonitor CRON[5814]: (safemonitor) CMD (bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh ^M)
```

I can't figure out what is "^M" at the end of each line.

CRON timming is working as expected, aplicacao.sh is doing what it has to do, but both, console.sh and comandos.sh, are not working.

Here is the "mail" sent from CRON:

```console
2021-08-11 11:30                                                  Page 1
    1   From: root (Cron Daemon)
    2   To: safemonitor
    3   Subject: Cron <safemonitor@safemonitor> bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh 
    4   MIME-Version: 1.0
    5   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
    6   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    7   X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
    8   X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/safemonitor>
    9   X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
   10   X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=safemonitor>
   11   
   12   TERM environment variable not set.
   13   
   14   
   15   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   16   |        V E R I F I C A   S E   P Y T H O N   E S T Á   R O D A N D O         |
   17   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   18   
   19   
   20   [11-08-2021_11-30-01] Python rodando! Nada a fazer, tchau ...
   21   
--------------
2021-08-11 11:31                                                  Page 1
    1   From: root (Cron Daemon)
    2   To: safemonitor
    3   Subject: Cron <safemonitor@safemonitor> bash /home/safemonitor/comandos.sh
    4   MIME-Version: 1.0
    5   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
    6   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    7   X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
    8   X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/safemonitor>
    9   X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
   10   X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=safemonitor>
   11   
: No such file or directoryitor/comandos.sh
--------------
2021-08-11 11:34                                                  Page 1
    1   From: root (Cron Daemon)
    2   To: safemonitor
    3   Subject: Cron <safemonitor@safemonitor> bash /home/safemonitor/comandos.sh
    4   MIME-Version: 1.0
    5   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
    6   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    7   X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
    8   X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/safemonitor>
    9   X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
   10   X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=safemonitor>
   11   
: No such file or directoryitor/comandos.sh
--------------
2021-08-11 11:34                                                  Page 1
    1   From: root (Cron Daemon)
    2   To: safemonitor
    3   Subject: Cron <safemonitor@safemonitor> bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/console.sh
    4   MIME-Version: 1.0
    5   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
    6   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    7   X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
    8   X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/safemonitor>
    9   X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
   10   X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=safemonitor>
   11   
: No such file or directoryitor/scripts/console.sh
--------------
2021-08-11 11:35                                                  Page 1
    1   From: root (Cron Daemon)
    2   To: safemonitor
    3   Subject: Cron <safemonitor@safemonitor> bash /home/safemonitor/scripts/aplicacao.sh 
    4   MIME-Version: 1.0
    5   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
    6   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    7   X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
    8   X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/safemonitor>
    9   X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
   10   X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=safemonitor>
   11   
   12   TERM environment variable not set.
   13   
   14   
   15   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   16   |        V E R I F I C A   S E   P Y T H O N   E S T Á   R O D A N D O         |
   17   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   18   
   19   
   20   [11-08-2021_11-35-01] Python rodando! Nada a fazer, tchau ...
   21   
--------------
2021-08-11 11:37                                                  Page 1
    1   From: root (Cron Daemon)
    2   To: safemonitor
    3   Subject: Cron <safemonitor@safemonitor> bash /home/safemonitor/comandos.sh
    4   MIME-Version: 1.0
    5   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
    6   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    7   X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
    8   X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/safemonitor>
    9   X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
   10   X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=safemonitor>
   11   
: No such file or directoryitor/comandos.sh
--------------
```

First thing is that the mail is truncating last line, don't know why:

*(
: No such file or directoryitor/scripts/console.sh
and
: No such file or directoryitor/comandos.sh )*

To get this mail output I created a executable file at */usr/sbin/sendmail* with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >> /tmp/sendmail.$(whoami) 2>&1
pr -Fn
echo --------------
```

This is the hole story. Hope I could provide all information.

Any idea is very, very welcome!!

Comment: You might want to check out: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Great, I'll do it. Thank you!

Comment: `: No such file or directory` ... `itor/comandos.sh`, something is breaking the full path here, seems like a line feed befor 'itor'

Comment: Solved! I created a text file with cron table, used dos2unix do correct it and uploaded to cron. Also run dos2unix on all my scripts and now it is working properly.

Comment: The ^M is a carriage return character:  or `\r`.    It comes from using non-Linux line conventions (such as from a MSDOS or Microsoft).